# Can anyone identify this light switch brand?

Tags: electrical, lighting

We've got a bunch of light switches and covers in our house but in the process of removing them to paint around them, one got broken.  Can anyone help me identify it?  They were put in by the builder of our townhouse (Sydney, Australia) which was constructed in the last five years or so.

The first picture is of an unbroken switch of the same style.  The second picture is of the naked (uncovered) switch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you unscrew the cover plate, you should be able to read the switch info right off the switch. Anything that recent should have at least the manufacturer and possibly even the model number on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your switch and cover plate look very similar to the XLP770 series as shown here:

[image]

See here for a distributor web page:

http://www.sparkydirect.com.au/p/935748/switch-1-gang-10amp-250v-white-hpm-xlp7701we.html

See here for manufacturer's Excel Range brochure:

http://www.hpm.com.au/Uploads/HPM%20excel%20range.pdf

Comment: They are the HPM XLP. I have seen tons of them in my life. If they were a Clipsal product the switches would clip into the wallplate and all Clipsal products have a Clipsal logo on them regardless of what the item is.